# Replacing data source of ArcMap Service Layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, map-service, image-service

I have many map documents that point to a hosted imagery service layer that has changed names.

I would like to write an ArcPy script that will replace the data sources of service layers that have changed names.  So far I have tried the following from the Python window, without success (assuming the only layer in the MXD is the service layer):

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
sourceURL = lyr.serviceProperties["URL"]
arcpy.AddMessage("Source URL: {0}".format(sourceURL))
destURL = "https:\path\to\image\service"
arcpy.AddMessage("Destination URL: {0}".format(destURL))

lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(sourceURL, destURL)

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save()
```

Comment: What happens when you try that?  Do you get any errors, or nothing changes at all?  Or something else?

Comment: I assume `connectionProperties` is a dictionary with your new values?

Comment: @Midavalo, I do not get any errors, but when I re-inspect the layer service properties, the URL has not changed.  Same thing if I save the MXD, close, reopen, and re-inspect.  It appears nothing has changed.  I've updated the `destURL` variable to be more generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to do it this way, and the reason is because service layers do not support workspace paths. You can test this on your layer by `lyr.supports("WORKSPACEPATH")`, which should return `False`.  However you could use `UpdateLayer` to replace the old service layer with a new one you create with the correct URL. I'm pretty sure to do it this way, though, the mxd can't be opened, so you'd have to run it from a standalone script:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path to your .mxd)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
newLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(new service .lyr)
oldLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, oldLayer, newLayer, False)
mxd.save()
```

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatelayer.htm